# How to run each project with its own worker at the same time?

Tags: typescript, parallel-processing, playwright

I have developed a test suite with playwright (**TypeScript**) that has **4 projects** (each project is to run the suite against our webshop in different countries: SE, DK, Nl, NO).

Running the suite with lets say **4 workers** doesn't limit 1 worker for each project so I can have two test executed on DK at the same time that might interfere with each other since I only have 1 user that can run these tests.

**I would like to be able to run my 4 countries at the same time but then they would run the tests in sequence as if there were only 1 worker**.

Do any of you have a setup in mind that could accomplish this?

**Note**: My setup is a custom made config that sends in the country specific url, username and password to each project. The tests are all re-used on each country.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Temporary Solution:

I have installed the npm run all package and run my scripts like this:

```
"test-dk-headless-retry": "playwright test --headed --workers=1 --retries=3 --project=DK-Webshop",
"test-se-headless-retry": "playwright test --headed --workers=1 --retries=3 --project=SE-Webshop",
"test-no-headless-retry": "playwright test --headed --workers=1 --retries=3 --project=NO-Webshop",
"test-nl-headless-retry": "playwright test --headed --workers=1 --retries=3 --project=NL-Webshop",
"test-parallel": "npm-run-all -p test-dk-headless-retry test-se-headless-retry test-no-headless-retry test-nl-headless-retry"
```

So the "test-parallel" will run all my projects with 1 worker at a time but all projects at the same time. This also works with my allure reporting and will still report ALL projects. So for now it's fine. Ultimately I would move it to run on their own machine by expanding on this.

Leaving this answer here if anyone comes with similar problem. If anyone has a "smarter" solution please share.